# Change image name of global variable - swift

Tags: swift, global-variables

I'm creating a Snake Game using swift and the library SpriteKit.

At the top of my program I declare a variable

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "head")


    [...]
}
```

In this way I can access to this variable in all of my functions. But I'd like to change the snake's image when the it moves.
For example, if the snake moves Up, I'd like to display the image of the snake looking up.

So I have this code to control the movements of the snake

```
if movesController[0]==true{
   playerY += 56.0000000
}
if movesController[1]==true{
   playerY -= 56.0000000
}
if movesController[2]==true{
   playerX += 56.0000000
}
if movesController[3]==true{
   playerX -= 56.0000000
}
```

and to change the image of the snake I thought I could just do this

```
if movesController[0]==true{
   playerY += 56.0000000
   player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "head_up")
}
if movesController[1]==true{
   playerY -= 56.0000000
   player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "head_down")
}
if movesController[2]==true{
   playerX += 56.0000000
   player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "head_right")
}
if movesController[3]==true{
   playerX -= 56.0000000
   player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "head_left")
}
```

But adding this 4 lines, the Snake is unable to move...
So I tried changing the declaration of the `player` variable

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var imageName = "head"
    var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\("imageName)")

    [...]
}
```

and then change the 4 lines I added before with `imageName = "move_up"` (or down - left - right)

But at the start of the program it gave me an error

```
Cannot use instance member 'imageName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

What should I do? My last option is to create another `playerVariable` and put it above the real snake image, but it would mean adding more nodes for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change player's texture, but not create new player at each step. Try add this function:

```
func changeHead(imageNamed name: String){
   player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: name)
}
```

And the program text will be changed in this way:

```
if movesController[0]==true{
   playerY += 56.0000000
   changeHead(imageNamed: "head_up")
}
if movesController[1]==true{
   playerY -= 56.0000000
   changeHead(imageNamed: "head_down")
}
if movesController[2]==true{
   playerX += 56.0000000
   changeHead(imageNamed: "head_right")
}
if movesController[3]==true{
   playerX -= 56.0000000
   changeHead(imageNamed: "head_left")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your way to solve this problem is true.Put self before the imageName variable. It would be work.

```
  import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var imageName = "head"
    var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\("self.imageName)")

    [...]
}
```